# Member not found 0x80020003 SSIS

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

Trying to use SSIS in Visual Studio 2019 Community. I am able to create a new "integration project" Project in VS. However, when I try to "Add New Item" in the Project, I get the error message:

> Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003
> (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))

Please help me to resolve this error... any detailed leads would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: hi  there is component where path issue or permission issue.  need more detail to debug

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley I have the same error. This should be the way to add a package based on a custom template.

If you just want to create a package from scratch, you can right click the node "SSIS Packages" and click "New SSIS Package".
[image]